# how to enable PDO SQLITE in php 8.2.12 for apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache

I already removed the commas...

```
extension=odbc
extension=openssl
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

I also entered the address, however it only activated PDO MYSQL and PDO ODBC:

```
extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"
```

Look information php:

PDO
PDO support
PDO drivers  mysql, odbc

I've searched a lot and haven't found a solution, please help me!

I need to activate PDO SQULITE not shown in:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Please look and uncomment this ```extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll``` and ```extension=php_sqlite.dll``` in **php.ini**, then restart *Apache*.

Comment: I tested again with ph extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll but nothing changed from when it was extension=pdo_sqlite.  In both cases it appears in cmd (php -m) but does not appear in phpinfo() nor does it execute. But with extension=php_sqlite.dll it doesn't even appear in cmd

Comment: Uncomment this ```extension=sqlite``` also. Remove the extension *.dll* as I said earlier

Comment: it hasn't worked yet

Comment: Make sure ```php_pdo_sqlite``` and ```php_sqlite``` DLL files are present in your ```extension_dir```.

Comment: Only php_pdo_sqlite and php_sqlite3 are present, but in php_sqlite3 I have already removed the comment.

Comment: ```I use Apache 2.4 and PHP 12```, There's no PHP 12, latest is PHP 8, what version of PHP you installed?

Comment: I made a mistake in the comment, see the title (php 8.2.12)

Comment: Try to re-install sqlite again using ```pecl install pdo_sqlite``` and add ```extesion=pdo_sqlite.so``` in ```php.ini```. Make sure that your file ```index.php``` have ```phpinfo();``` content and placed in your *Apache>htdocs* and restart *Apache service* then navigate in browser use ```http://localhost/phpinfo.php```. If still not working, better to provide more details like *folder structure* or image of *php folder*,*Apache folder*,*extension directories*,*etc.*, that will be use to solve your problem.

Comment: Is this command from Linux? I use Windows. I've already done all the tests on another computer and reinstalled it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using web server package like xampp;
you just have to uncomment the extension=pdo_sqlite in php.ini
and restart apache.

If not, then you must install the pdo sqlite extension first
like this:
`sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`.

Comment: I use Apache 2.4 and PHP 12 separately, on Windows. These commands are for Linux

Comment: Is your apache and php newly installed? If yes, try to reinstall, sometimes apache or php can be installed but still have issues.

Comment: I installed sqlite3 on Windows but it didn't work (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite/). I've already reinstalled it on two other computers but it doesn't work.

Comment: I see, you're using sqlite3. In that case you just have to uncomment the ;extension=sqlite3 then restart apache